# Possible cause of noise in cosmic radio signals

Tags: probability, noise

In any region of space there is a background of cosmic radiation - such as that from the big bang.

This radiation may be detected by an aerial and then amplified - resulting in a detected signal.  If the radiaion were constant,then the signal would be consant also - an assumption!

What appens if there is an absense of signal for a short period? Obviosly it is detected as ”noise”.

The question is therefore: “What is the probability that this noise is caused by flucuations in the number of photons present”. In particular: “What is the probability that in a small region of space, there are no photons existing for a specific period?”

The answer will relate the size of the region, the time for which no radiation is present and how often such a situation exists for!

Together these will give a spectral distribution and amplitude for such “Radiation Gap Noise”!

Comment: this seems more like a physics question to me... anyway, I don't understand very well what you are looking for here, is it really a *probability* what you are looking for? Because the problem is not that clear to make such a calculation. Perhaps your just looking for some information about noise?